# Define key-chord key with specific mode

Tags: emacs

How do you define a key-chord key only in specific mode, for example I want to bind a cider repl to a specific key only in `clojure-mode` or `cider-mode`. I can only find an example that activates the key globally.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

```
(require 'evil)
(require 'key-chord)
(evil-mode 1)

(key-chord-mode 1)
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jk" 'evil-normal-state)
(key-chord-define-global "gt" 'other-window)
(key-chord-define clojure-mode-hook "gj" 'cider-jack-in)
;; error : Wrong type argument: keymapp, (rainbow-delimiters-mode)


(provide 'init-evil)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Defining mode-specific key bindings

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
(define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'cider-repl)
```

... where of course you would have to replace `cider-repl` with the specific command you want to bind. Note that the quote `'` before the command name is required.

To generalize:

```
(define-key <mode-map> <key-binding> '<command>)
```

---

#### [`key-chord`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyChord)-specific instructions

You need to change the line where you're trying to set up the `clojure-mode`-specific key binding to

```
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 
          (lambda () (key-chord-define clojure-mode-map "gj" 'cider-jack-in)))
```

---

#### Appendix: Making sure mode-maps are defined before modifying them

In order for modifications to `clojure-mode-map` to work properly, you have to make sure it is defined when you call `define-key` as described above.

If you are using the Emacs Package Manager, you are likely to have this line

```
(package-initialize)
```

somewhere in your `.emacs` file (which takes care of loading packages installed via `package-install`). Make sure you call `define-key` somewhere *below this line*.

Alternatively you can add the call to `define-key` to the [hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html) that is run when `clojure-mode` is enabled:

```
(defun clojure-set-up-key-bindings ()
  (define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'cider-repl)
  ;; If necessary, add more calls to `define-key' here ...
  )

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'clojure-set-up-key-bindings)
```

Comment: You would usually hook this in `clojure-mode-hook` because `clojure-mode-map` is not defined when your `.emacs` file is read.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, thanks. I added a description of how to do this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm looking for `key-chord` specific answer, since I already know how to do it the normal way. Anyway I still tried your code with how `key-chord` define its key. Please take a look, as it still gives me an error.

Comment: @FarisNasution I see. Please add the exact code you are using and the error you are getting to your question.

Comment: @FarisNasution Thanks for adding the code. I'm not too familiar with `key-chord-mode`, but I think what you need to do is change the last line before the `;; error: ...` comment to: `(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook (lambda () (key-chord-define clojure-mode-map "gj" 'cider-jack-in)))`. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @FarisNasution You're welcome. Answer modified to include final solution.